# TFS RM - Release - Commits details

Tags: tfs-2015, ms-release-management

Does anyone knows how the commits from a release are determined?

From my tests it resulted that is taking into the consideration the last commit even if that commit was associated with a build was triggered couple of builds ago.

In the below screenshots it's displayed that all three last releases are using changeset 47512 which quite confusing for me:

Release 10-01:
[image]

Release 09-01:
[image]

Release 08-01:
[image]

Comment: I believe there's a bug in the logic for the commit tab in TFS 2015.2... I'm trying to find a source confirming.

Answer (score 1):

Release shows the difference between w.r.t last release. While showing the difference, it shows the difference between the builds used in the two releases.

Let me explain with some example. Say there are Release1 (with buildA having commit A,B,C) , Release2(with buildB having commit D,E,F) and Release3 (with buildC having commit G,H,,I) and Release4 (with buildC having commit G,H,I).

Here commit tab of Release3 will show the diff w.r.t Release2 and it should show G,H,I.

Similarly commit tab of Release4 will show the diff w.r.t Release3 and it should show 'No diff' as build used is same.

Comment: Based on my tests it shows G, H, I and D,E,F also which is confusing.